# Python Join List

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I was recently reading about VIF function implementation in python and I came across this article.

[Link to the article](https://etav.github.io/python/vif_factor_python.html)

I am not able to understand the operation which is taking place in this particular line.

```
features = "+".join(df.columns - ["annual_inc"])
```

I understand what would be the output when the statement is

```
features = "+".join(df.columns)
```

Can anyone explain what is the significance of `- ["annual_inc"]` in the statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is used old pandas code, now raise error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','annual_inc'])

print (df.columns - ["annual_inc"])
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

So use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) for exclude values of list from columns names:

```
print(df.columns.difference(["annual_inc"]))
Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')

features = "+".join(df.columns.difference(["annual_inc"]))
print(features)
a+b
```

Answer (score 1):

`"annual_inc"` is the target variable of the regression, and therefore is excluded from the set of features.

Answer (score 1):

For `patsy.dmatrices` the first arument of the function is `formula_like`, which has to be a string like `y ~ x1 + x2`. Here in `features` , you are creating a string with all columns (join with a `+` in between) except your target variable which is `annual_inc`. Next you have to creaate the input string to `formula_like` , ie `target ~ variable1 + variable2 + ...`, in your case `'annual_inc ~' + features`.

```
dmatrices('annual_inc ~' + features, df, return_type='dataframe')
```

refer [patsy.dmatrices](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html#patsy.dmatrices)